# How to keep springboot application alive after exiting putty

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am running my spring boot application on my server using putty via command 
mvn spring-boot:run and it runs only when I have open ssh session. Is it possible to keep application alive after I disconnect session?
Or do I have to make executable war file and deploy to installed tomcat server on my ubunntu 14.04. 
I know others ways to deploy boot apps but I want to know if it is possible in my approach.

Comment: MagGGG As shown in my answer, It would be good to generate the log file with a specific name (like spring-log.txt or server-log.txt) to find for any errors for debugging.

Comment: besides nohup, you can use a detachable `screen` session (e.g. https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen) and spring boot specifically supports running as system service: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the command in the background and with nohup like so

nohup mvn spring-boot:run &

When you do this, the application runs in background even after you close ssh session.

Answer (score 3):

In putty, you need to use `nohup mvn spring-boot:run > spring-log.txt &` to run the command in the background and this generates the `spring-log.txt` file.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want console logs to be written (you have logging frameworks which handles the application logs) then use this command

```
nohup mvn spring-boot:run </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

BTW, just curious, why are you using `mvn spring-boot:run` to run your program in your server? doesn't that require you to have maven runtime installed in your server as well?

Comment: Yes I had to install maven as well. Of course java -jar target/myproject_name.jar can be used too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying your executable jar

```
nohup java -jar <your jar name>
```