# Is using nohup in production is a bad practice ? (how to run server forever)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, web-deployment, digital-ocean, nohup

I have Linux Droplet on Digital Ocean, and I want to run on it some services – like SpringbootWeb and React.js.

> Clearly I need to run the servers all the time, without being depends
>   on the terminal on/off (I’m using Putty) and  I am planning to do it ,
>   **by using [nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40351418/9727918)**.

I saw other methods like those 
In [spring boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html) (See  3. Installing Spring Boot Applications) and in [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818202/how-to-run-node-js-app-forever-when-console-is-closed).
But I prefer for now use nohup since it’s easier and simpler.

**I there is problem with that approach and it considered “bad practice” for production ?**

(And if does, what considered a good practice ?)

**Edit**

- Now seeing that nohup not saving react running after closing Putty-console
- found also [this](https://dev.to/xarala221/the-easiest-way-to-deploy-a-react-web-application-2l8a) idea for deploying React on nginx. (Digital Ocean run nginx)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with it, but you would still need to create some sort of init script to start your app on boot and stop it on shutdown.

So on a Linux system you would typically want to use systemd unit files for this, and have the init system handle the lifecycle of your server application. The reference guide mentions it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-systemd-service), or refer to [this](https://medium.com/@manjiki/running-spring-boot-applications-as-system-services-on-linux-5ea5f148c39a) as a more complete example.